# Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'text')

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-jasmine

I'm looking into some code however when running the test i came across these errors: -

```
zone.js:690 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'text') ; Zone: ProxyZone ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'text')
    at eval (modal.service.spec.ts:288:58)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:386:30)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (proxy.js:117:43)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:385:36)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:143:47)
    at zone.js:891:38
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421:35)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (proxy.js:148:43)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420:40)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188:51) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'text')
    at eval (webpack:///./tests/unit/ng2/utils/modal/modal.service.spec.ts?:288:58)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9878/base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:386:30)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9878/base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:117:43)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9878/base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:385:36)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:9878/base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:143:47)
    at http://localhost:9878/base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:891:38
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:9878/base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:421:35)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:9878/base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:148:43)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:9878/base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:420:40)
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:9878/base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:188:51)**strong text**
```

Not entirly sure what is happening, think it might be an async issue but here is my code for the spec test

```
    it('tests text based modal window', (done: () => void) => {
    const config1: TextModalWindowConfig = {
        type: ModalTypes.textModal,
        heading: 'text based modal',
        id: 'testTextModal',
        text: 'text modal window content'
  };

  const modalData1 = service.open(config1);
  const modalWindow1 = modalData1.modalWindow;

  modalWindow1.container.dispatchEvent(MODAL_OPEN_EVENT);

  modalData1.afterOpen.then(() => {
      checkBasicModalStructure(modalWindow1, config1);
      expect((modalWindow1.childReference as any)._component.text).toEqual(config1.text);

      const config2 = Object.create(config1);

      config2.id = 'testTextModal2';
      const modalData2 = service.open(config2);
      const modalWindow2 = modalData2.modalWindow;

      modalWindow2.container.dispatchEvent(MODAL_OPEN_EVENT);

      modalData2.afterOpen.then(() => {
            expect(modalWindow1.overlay.classList.contains(ModalElementsClasses.GRAY_BG)).toBeFalsy();
          checkBasicModalStructure(modalWindow2, config2);

          spyOn((modalWindow2.container as any), 'animationEnd').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve());
          service.closeLast().then(() => {
                expect(modalWindow1.overlay.classList.contains(ModalElementsClasses.GRAY_BG)).toBeTruthy();
              done();
          });
      });
  });
});
```

The error occurs here :-

expect(modalWindow1.childReference._component.text).toEqual(config1.text);

Any ideas suggestion or fix would be great.

Comment: Hi @Stephen, i got the same error with " TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userConfig')". did you fix it ? Thanks in advance

Comment: is there any fix found yet?